# Navigation drop down menu CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, header, navbar

I am trying to position the nav on the right side in the middle of the header area. like [cyberchimps](https://cyberchimps.com/)

[image]

Also when I hover over sub menu of BGA I would like to keep hover state on for BGA. I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

I have seen "*" in CSS on a few examples, is that a good practice to use today?

I am doubtful that my approach is sound any suggestions are welcomed.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #CCC;
}

@font-face{
 src: url(assets/fonts/oswald-v16-latin-regular.ttf);
 font-family: oswald;
}

/* ~~ The header is given a width of 100%.
It will extend the full width of the browser. 
The rest of the layout will be fixed~~ */
header{
 background-color: #004489;
 min-width: 1024px;
 height: 100px;
 clear: both;
}
/*header::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}*/
.navWrapper{
 max-width: 1100px;
 margin: 0 auto;  
}

nav{
 float:right;
 margin-top: 20px;
 padding-right: 50px;
}

nav ul{
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 
}

nav ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 float: left; 
 position: relative;

}

nav ul li a{
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: oswald;
 font-size: 25px;
 color: #fff;
}


nav ul a:hover, nav ul a:active, nav ul a:focus{
 background-color: #065BB0;
}

nav ul ul{
 display: none;/**/
 position: absolute;
}

/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */
nav ul li:hover > ul {
 display:list-item; 
}
nav ul ul li{
 display: block;  
 width: 115px;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
nav ul ul li a{
 color:#242323;
 background-color: #8ec6ef;

}
nav ul ul a:hover, nav ul ul a:active, nav ul ul a:focus{
 color:#fff;
 background-color: #065BB0;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="navWrapper">  
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">BGA</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">BOOKS</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">COURSES</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>    
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible with CSS, you can simply do it by using jQuery `mouseenter` event:

```js
$('#bga-list').mouseenter(() => {
 $('#bga-list > ul').show();
})
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #CCC;
}

@font-face{
 src: url(assets/fonts/oswald-v16-latin-regular.ttf);
 font-family: oswald;
}

/* ~~ The header is given a width of 100%.
It will extend the full width of the browser. 
The rest of the layout will be fixed~~ */
header{
 background-color: #004489;
 min-width: 1024px;
 height: 100px;
 clear: both;
}
/*header::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}*/
.navWrapper{
 max-width: 1100px;
 margin: 0 auto;  
}

nav{
 float:right;
 margin-top: 20px;
 padding-right: 50px;
}

nav ul{
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 
}

nav ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 float: left; 
 position: relative;

}

nav ul li a{
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: oswald;
 font-size: 25px;
 color: #fff;
}


nav ul a:hover, nav ul a:active, nav ul a:focus{
 background-color: #065BB0;
}

nav ul ul{
 display: none;/**/
 position: absolute;
}

/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */

nav ul ul li{
 display: block;  
 width: 115px;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
nav ul ul li a{
 color:#242323;
 background-color: #8ec6ef;

}
nav ul ul a:hover, nav ul ul a:active, nav ul ul a:focus{
 color:#fff;
 background-color: #065BB0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="navWrapper">  
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
     <li id="bga-list"><a href="#">BGA</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">BOOKS</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">COURSES</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>    
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </header>
</body>
```

However, I don't think it's a good idea to show a dropdown list on `mouseenter` and never hide it. Hope this helps.